# Show Relations from Node to Node Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new to Neo4j, been playing around with it for a couple of days now.

I'm trying to use Neo4j to map our company's database by showing how one table is related to another (data is pulled to or pushed from one table to another) and what scripts are used to do this pulling and pushing. To do this, I'm using three different properties: TableName, ScriptName, and TableTouch.

- TableName: Table node which corresponds to the name of a table
- ScriptName: Script Node which corresponds to the script which
  updatesa table
- TableTouch: Used to show which table affects another
  table

Here is an example of the .CSV I'm importing:

```
TableName    ScriptName    TableTouch
Source       ScriptA       Water/Oil
Water        ScriptB       Source
Oil          ScriptC       Source
```

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Table) ASSERT c.TableName IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Scripts) ASSERT c.ScriptName IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:///C:\\NeoTest.CSV" AS line

MERGE (table:Table {TableName: UPPER(line.TableName)})
SET table.TableTouch = UPPER(line.TableTouch)
MERGE (script:Scripts {ScriptName: UPPER(line.ScriptName)})

MERGE (table) - [:UPDATED_BY] -> (script)
```

This will relate scripts to their appropriate tables and load in all the table and script nodes.

Now an example of what I need is for Node "Source" to connect to Node "Water" because "Source" = Water.TableTouch and "Water" = Source.TableTouch.

Assume any given table could have multiple tables listed in the TableTouch property.

I want the TableName nodes to connect to other TableName nodes where the TableName of one node is found in the TableName.TableTouch of another node. How would I go about doing this? Do I need to have my .CSV formatted differently for this?

Thanks,
-Andrew

Edit: This may make things more clear

What I have:

[image]
What I'd like to have (red arrows):[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

If I understand your scenario, you want to represent the Script that is used to generate each Table, and what other table was used by that Script.

And, if I understand the meaning of your CSV file and your pictures, it looks like the `Source` table is generated by `ScriptA` without using data from any other tables. If so, you can create your CSV file to look something like this (where the `Source` table row's `TableTouch` column has the special value `NOTHING` -- you can use some other name -- to indicate that column actually has no value):

```
TableName,ScriptName,TableTouch
Source,ScriptA,NOTHING
Water,ScriptB,Source
Oil,ScriptC,Source
```

#### Data model:

```
(src:Table {name: 'Source'})<-[:USES]-(s:Script {name: 'ScriptC'})-[:MAKES]->(dest:Table {name: 'Oil'})
```

*Note: This data model allows a single Script to "use" any number of source Tables and "make" any number of destination Tables.*

#### Create Constraints

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Table) ASSERT t.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Script) ASSERT s.name IS UNIQUE;
```

#### Import data

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:\\NeoTest.CSV" AS line
MERGE (src:Table     {name: line.TableTouch})
MERGE (dest:Table    {name: line.TableName})
MERGE (script:Script {name: line.ScriptName})
MERGE (script)-[:USES]->(src)
MERGE (script)-[:MAKES]->(dest)
```

*Note: To keep the query simple, we just go ahead and create (at most) one `NOTHING` node to represent the absence of a source Table.*

#### Results

[image]

Comment: I added some pictures which may make when I'm trying to describe a little more clear. If there is a better way to set up the CSV, that's fine, I wasn't really sure what the best approach was to start with.